# How to send iOS data to Azure mobile service database?

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to swift and Azure and am trying to send some data from my swift app up to my azure mobile database.  I have an app with CoreData working but after fetching my data i'm running into difficulties sending it up to azure. I'm trying to use the insert table method from the azure framework.

I've tried this method:

```
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://mymobileapp.azure-mobile.net/", applicationKey: "aAaBbBcCc…")

var client = AppDelegate().client // To reference my constant in AppDelegate.swift

var itemTable:MSTable = client.tableWithName("Item")
var itemToInsert:NSDictionary = ["text":"My Awesome Item 1"]

itemTable.insert(itemToInsert,
    completion: {
        insertedItem, error in
        if error{
            println("error: \(error)")
        }
        else{
            println("Success!")
        }
    }
)
```

But I'm running into problems with the application key. From what I can gather, the application keys are no longer used in Azure Mobile Apps.

I've also tried the method shown in the Mobile App QuickStart guide for swift but the code seems to be for an older version of swift.

I'm not trying to display a table in my app just upload data to the database.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is applicationKey: "aAaBbBcCc…" is the actual key or just here you have typed it like this.

Comment: Are you using the Quickstart downloaded from the new Azure portal for Azure Mobile Apps?  The code is also available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/iOS-Swift

Comment: @ArunGupta I have been trying it without a key. As the key has been removed from Azure MobileApps see [link] (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Implementing-Application-Key)

Like this:
'let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://mymobileapp.azure-mobile.net")'

Comment: @lindydonna-msft Ya i've downloaded that code and have been looking at it in Xcode. I'm struggling to see where the data is actually sent to the Azure database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work. The application key is no longer used in the new Azure Mobile Apps. In addition to deleting the key you have to add a new property, specifically a App Transport Security property, to allow for a connection with an unsecured HTTP site.

```
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://mymobileapp.azure-mobile.net/")

var client = AppDelegate().client // To reference my constant in AppDelegate.swift

var itemTable:MSTable = client.tableWithName("Item")
var itemToInsert:NSDictionary = ["text":"My Awesome Item 1"]

itemTable.insert(itemToInsert,
    completion: {
        insertedItem, error in
        if error{
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        else{
            print("Success!")
        }
    }
)
```